# Neo4J. Remove intermediate nodes keep relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, relationship

I've got the following node-relationship:

```
a-->b-->c-->d
```

Now I'd like to remove the nodes `b` and `c` and reconnect the both nodes `a` and `d` like that:

```
a-->d
```

Is this possible with cypher?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how your model looks like and what results you are expecting.

```
MATCH (a:LABEL1)-[r1]->(b:LABEL2)-[r2]->(c:LABEL3)-[r3]->(d:LABEL4) 
CREATE (a)-[:REL]->(d) 
DELETE r1, r2, r3, b, c
```